# Why doesn't construction heuristic work when planning variable is nullable

Tags: optaplanner

I’m trying to make a schedule for cashiers using optaplanner 5.5.0. A planning entity is the same as at the nurserostering example(shiftAssignment), but a planning variable (employee) is nullable (there can be unassigned shifts). So TS works perfectly, but construction heuristic(First Fit) does nothing (because in my case a solution with all nulls is feasible, I suppose). What should I do to make construction heuristic working?

Answer (score 1):

Up to at least *6.0.0.Beta2*, the construction heuristics don't support `@PlanningVariable(nullable=true)` (which is new since *6.0.0.Beta1*) yet.

I am working on refactoring the construction heuristics so they are based on the Selector architecture and the placer stuff. This will yield many benefits for the CH, including `nullable=true` support.

Comment: One workaround is to use a CustomSolverPhase and mimic First Fit (Decreasing) in there. Another workaround is to keep the CH but use nullable=false and introduce a dummy value (and make your score constraint rules smart enough to threat that dummy value as null).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `6.0.0.CR1` the construction heuristics support nullable variables. It's already released, see optaplanner.org.