# Step changes listener in construction heuristic phase

Tags: drools, optaplanner

In OptaPlanner, I noticed that there is variable changes listener for every move. And `SolverEventListener` for `bestSolutionChanged` which is calculated after every phases. However, I could not find to catch the changes in each step end.

Any suggestions to listen the Step changes in Construction Heuristic phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen to to events on a level of steps and phases, you 'll need to use an internal listener called `PhaseLifecycleListener`. For example the internal benchmarker code uses it:

```
StepScoreSingleStatisticListener listener = new StepScoreSingleStatisticListener();
((DefaultSolver) solver).addPhaseLifecycleListener(listener);
// solver.solve(...);
((DefaultSolver) solver).removePhaseLifecycleListener(listener);
```

The implementation could look something like this:

```
private class StepScoreSingleStatisticListener extends PhaseLifecycleListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void stepEnded(AbstractStepScope stepScope) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Warning: This is internal API, not backwards compatible in future releases, not documented, not for the faint hearted, use at own risk, you're not in Kansas anymore Dorothy, ... :)

Comment: Make sure to read up about "scopes (solver, phase, step, move)" in the docs first.

Comment: Is this answer up to date? I too was surprised that my `SolverEventListener` was not called during CH. I noticed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666703) that CH now supports `nullable` planning variables (thank you!), which led me to believe that solutions with null-values are "legit" and reasonable to report as "new best" solutions. Also, the docs even say "The `BestSolutionChangedEvent`'s `newBestSolution` may not be initialized or feasible." (although the comment in the source says "The `PlanningSolution` is guaranteed to be initialized" so I'm confused).

Comment: Do you use nullable=true? You might be running into https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/25

Comment: Yes, I use `nullable=true`. Seems likely that I'm running into this. This backport has not been released yet though, right? Your comment was from May 26 and the last 8-release seems to be from May 3.